Should route groups or dynamic routes be used if building a folder structure from a schemaType?
Experimenting with Next.js 14 and using Sanity 3.30.1 trying to setup my folder structure based on the Sanity schemaTypes, two of which are singletons:
homePage
path: singleton/homePage.ts
content:
import {HomeIcon} from '@sanity/icons'
import {defineField} from 'sanity'


export default defineField({
  name: 'home',
  title: 'Home',
  type: 'document',
  icon: HomeIcon,
  // stripped code   
})

errorPage
path: singleton/errorPage.ts
content:
import {defineField} from 'sanity'
import {MdErrorOutline} from 'react-icons/md'

export default defineField({
  name: 'error',
  title: 'Error',
  type: 'document',
  icon: MdErrorOutline,
  // stripped code   
})

with one document that isn't setup as a singleton:
page
import {defineField} from 'sanity'
import {DocumentIcon} from '@sanity/icons'

export default defineField({
  name: 'page',
  title: 'Page',
  type: 'document',
  icon: DocumentIcon,
  // stripped code   
})

Schema Types
setup with a structure of:
home
import {ListItemBuilder} from 'sanity/structure'
import defineStructure from '../utils/defineStructure'

export default defineStructure<ListItemBuilder>((S) =>
  S.listItem()
    .title('Home Page')
    .schemaType('home')
    .child(S.editor().title('Home').schemaType('home').documentId('home'))
)

error
import {ListItemBuilder} from 'sanity/structure'
import defineStructure from '../utils/defineStructure'

export default defineStructure<ListItemBuilder>((S) =>
  S.listItem()
    .title('Error Page')
    .schemaType('error')
    .child(S.editor().title('Error').schemaType('error').documentId('errorPage'))
)

page
import {ListItemBuilder} from 'sanity/structure'
import defineStructure from '../utils/defineStructure'
import {DocumentsIcon} from '@sanity/icons'

export default defineStructure<ListItemBuilder>((S) =>
  S.listItem()
    .title('Pages')
    .icon(DocumentsIcon)
    .schemaType('page')
    .child(S.documentTypeList('page'))
)

in my Next.js project in the app folder if I want to build based on the schemaType should I be using Route Groups:
/app
  (home) // root `/`
  (error) // 404 page
  (page)
    [slug]

or should I be using Dynamic Routes
/app
  [home] // root `/`
  [error] // 404 page
  [page]
    [slug]

what is the correct routing approach to allowing content to be modified in Sanity and updated on the frontend of a Next.js project based on the schemaType?
Is this approach ok or should I be doing it a different way?
Not finding much when it comes to wanting to customized from Sanity the root and error pages of a site.

I would definitely recommend using Route Groups instead of Dynamic Routes here. Dynamic routes are intended to be used when you have multiple paths that can be generated at build time or runtime. For example, in your case, /[slug], where [slug] can generate multiple different routes such as /page1, /page2, etc.
Route Groups are great for grouping your pages together to either use a similar layout.tsx/error.tsx, or simply for organization.
In this use case, you're using the folders simply for organization, so Route Groups would be the way to go.
To break it down further, since you know home and error are singletons with pre-defined routes, there's no need for multiple paths to be built, and I'd go with Route Groups for those. Similarly for the page directory, since you're also using that for organization, (I'm guessing you don't want to have a route with two-levels of dynamism, eg. /page1/subpage1, /page2/subpage2), a Route Group for that folder would also be best.
Hope this helps!
